# Array inside array on schema

Tags: arrays, schema, connector, looker-studio

I´m developing a connector for data studio and I have the schema below:

```
            var azulDataSchema = [
              {
                name: 'NUMBER',
                label: 'SALE NUMBER',
                dataType: 'STRING',
                semantics: {
                  conceptType: 'DIMENSION'
                }
              },
              {
                name: 'STATUS',
                label: 'SALE STATUS',
                dataType: 'STRING',
                semantics: {
                  conceptType: 'DIMENSION'
                }
              }, 
              {
                name: 'CUSTOMER_NAME',
                label: 'CUSTOMER NAME',
                dataType: 'STRING',
                semantics: {
                  conceptType: 'DIMENSION'
                }
              },  
              {
                name: 'PAYMENT_INSTALLMENTS_NUMBER',
                label: 'PAYMENT_INSTALLMENTS_NUMBER',
                dataType: 'STRING',
                semantics: {
                  conceptType: 'DIMENSION',      
                }
              },
              {
                name: 'PAYMENT_INSTALLMENTS_VALUE',
                label: 'PAYMENT_INSTALLMENTS_VALUE',
                dataType: 'NUMBER',
                semantics: {
                  conceptType: 'METRIC',
                  isReaggregatable: true
                }
              },
              {
                name: 'PAYMENT_INSTALLMENTS_STATUS',
                label: 'PAYMENT_INSTALLMENTS_STATUS',
                dataType: 'STRING',
                semantics: {
                  conceptType: 'DIMENSION'
                }
              }
            ]
```

> **So, for one SALE (identified by NUMBER), I can have ONE or MORE
>   PAYMENT INSTALLMENTS.**
>
> ```
>         **The response of API is:**
> ```

```
        [
           {
              "id":"58fe71af-a9d5-410d-b729-db9b2c7494d3",
              "number":3,
              "status":"COMMITTED",
              "customer":{
                 "name":"CLIENTE JOSÉ"
              },
              "payment":{
                 "installments":[
                    {
                       "number":1,
                       "value":8,
                       "status":"PENDING"
                    },
                    {
                       "number":2,
                       "value":8,
                       "status":"PENDING"
                    },
                    {
                       "number":3,
                       "value":8,
                       "status":"PENDING"
                    },
                    {
                       "number":4,
                       "value":8,
                       "status":"PENDING"
                    },
                    {
                       "number":5,
                       "value":8,
                       "status":"PENDING"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              "total":80
           }
        ]
```

> **And my function to pass the data for Data Studio is:**

```
function getData(request) {  
      var dataSchema = [];          

      request.fields.forEach(function(field) {
        for (var i = 0; i < azulDataSchema.length; i++) {
          if (azulDataSchema[i].name === field.name) {
            dataSchema.push(azulDataSchema[i]);
            break;
          }
        }
      });     

      var response = scriptProperties.getProperty("Data");    
      response = JSON.parse(response);     

      var data = [];            


  try{
    //begin object keys foreach
    Object.keys(response).forEach(function(sale) {       
      var values = [];      

      //begin dataSchema foreach
      dataSchema.forEach(function(field) { 

        switch(field.name){          
          case 'NUMBER':          
            if(response[sale].number != undefined && response[sale].number != null){             
              values.push(response[sale].number.toString());
            }
            break;         
          case 'STATUS':
            if(response[sale].status != undefined &&
               response[sale].status != null){             
              values.push(response[sale].status); 
            }          
            break;
          case 'CUSTOMER_NAME':     
            if(response[sale].customer != undefined &&
               response[sale].customer != null){              
              values.push(response[sale].customer.name);
            }
            break;         

           //BEGIN INSTALLMENTS  
            //*******FROM HERE, SOMETHING IS NOT CORRECT*****
          case 'PAYMENT_INSTALLMENTS_NUMBER' :
            if(response[sale].payment.installments != null){  
               response[sale].payment.installments.forEach(function (installmentNumber){                                 
                values.push(installmentNumber.number.toString());                                  
              });  
            }
            break;            
          case 'PAYMENT_INSTALLMENTS_VALUE':
            if(response[sale].payment.installments != null){        
              response[sale].payment.installments.forEach(function (installmentValue){                        
                values.push(installmentValue.value);   
              });                       
            }
            break;          
          case 'PAYMENT_INSTALLMENTS_STATUS':
            if(response[sale].payment.installments != null){  
              response[sale].payment.installments.forEach(function (installmentStatus){                            
               values.push(installmentStatus.status);
              });              
            }
            break;

            //END INSTALLMENTS
            case 'TOTAL':
            if(response[sale].total != undefined){

              values.push(response[sale].total); 
            }else{
              values.push(0);
            }          
            break;    
          default:          
            values.push("");

        }//END swith case

      }); //END dataSchema foreach   

      data.push({
        values: values,
      });

    });//END object keys foreach

  }catch(error){
    Logger.log('ERRO: ' + error);    
  }
      return {
        schema: dataSchema,
        rows: data
      };
    };//END function
```

> **The way the data is being passed to Data Studio is:**

```
[
   {
      "values":[
         "JOSÉ", //customer name
         "3", //number of sale
         "1", //installment number (of this sale)
         "2", //installment number (of this sale)
         "3", //installment number (of this sale)
         "4", //installment number (of this sale)
         "5", //installment number (of this sale)
         "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
         "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
         "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
         "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
         "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
         8, //installment value (of this sale)
         8, //installment value (of this sale)
         8, //installment value (of this sale)
         8, //installment value (of this sale)
         8, //installment value (of this sale)
         "COMMITTED", //sale status
         80 //total sale
      ]
   }
]
```

> **So, with a forEach I´m trying to pass a list of INSTALLMENTS for one SALE, but when I try to see it in Data Studio I get the error code
>   (0e99578d):[ERROR DATA STUDIO][1]**
>
> ```
>       [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxTED.png
>
> Help me please rs
>
> Thanks
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`getData` should have a 1-to-1 mapping from the `field.name` to a value, and the values need to be scalar (i.e. `string`, `number`, or `boolean`). If there are 3 `fields` in the `getData` request, your response should have three entries. (i.e something like `{"values":[1, 2, 3]}`) Currently, your `getData` response is returning 19 entries when the schema expects there to be 6.

For your specific use case, there are two ways to solve this.

### Make a new row for each installment number, status, and value.

Following this approach, your `getData` response look something like the following:

```
[
  {
    "values": [
      "JOSÉ", //customer name
      "3", //number of sale
      "1", //installment number (of this sale)
      "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
      8, //installment value (of this sale)
      "COMMITTED", //sale status
      80 //total sale
    ]
  },
  {
    "values": [
      "JOSÉ", //customer name
      "3", //number of sale
      "2", //installment number (of this sale)
      "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
      8, //installment value (of this sale)
      "COMMITTED", //sale status
      80 //total sale
    ]
  },
  {
    "values": [
      "JOSÉ", //customer name
      "3", //number of sale
      "3", //installment number (of this sale)
      "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
      8, //installment value (of this sale)
      "COMMITTED", //sale status
      80 //total sale
    ]
  },
  {
    "values": [
      "JOSÉ", //customer name
      "3", //number of sale
      "4", //installment number (of this sale)
      "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
      8, //installment value (of this sale)
      "COMMITTED", //sale status
      80 //total sale
    ]
  },
  {
    "values": [
      "JOSÉ", //customer name
      "3", //number of sale
      "5", //installment number (of this sale)
      "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
      8, //installment value (of this sale)
      "COMMITTED", //sale status
      80 //total sale
    ]
  }
]
```

### Aggregate your fields

If it makes sense for your data, you can aggregate these fields by summing, averaging, or any other aggregation that takes the multiple values for each schema field and turns them into a scalar value.

Following this approach, your `getData` response would look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "values": [
      "JOSÉ", //customer name
      "3", //number of sale
      "PENDING", //installment status (of this sale)
      40, //installment value (of this sale) (This was the result of summing all installment values)
      "COMMITTED", //sale status
      400 //total sale (This was the result of summing all total sale values)
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that I removed the installment number entry since it probably wouldn't make sense if the values were being aggregated.

Please see [getData](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getdata) in the Data Studio Community Connectors reference for any additional detail.